# Slack Upload Email using API

Tags: upload, slack, slack-api

I´m trying to upload an email (I have the html code) to slack.
I know that there is a possiblity to upload files using a slack email adress, but in my case I cannot use it.

I used the slack api method [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) for this, but the files only appear as code lines and not as html content.

Comment: I reckon that's not possible, since Slack doesn't have any API to upload emails.

Comment: Slack mentions "email" as accepted file type (https://api.slack.com/types/file#file_types).
But am not able to send .eml file. @RayUp Can you help with any solution you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can upload emails to Slack, but only as plain text files using `files.upload`. That however works pretty well.

To upload a plain text file with `files.upload` sent the file contents as string in `content` (this must be sent via a POST) and set `filetype` to `text`.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think he meant to have the HTML preview and not the HTML posted as a text snippet (which looks horrible).

Comment: I agree, but as mentioned I do no think that is possible.